# Why are the number of row results always different to the number of data frame rows and how can I make them match?

Tags: r, for-loop

I use this loop to connect to Elasticsearch, retrieve some data and add it into my data frame based on a common identifier:

```
library(elastic); library(jsonlite)

for (i in first_chats_eu$associate) {

  firstchats_eu_body <- paste0(
    '{"size":1,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"associate":"',
    i
    ,'"}},{"term":{"type":"conversation-archived"}}]}},"sort":{"time":"asc"}}'
  )

  firstchats_eu_connection <- Search(
    index = "my_index",
    type = "my_type",
    body = firstchats_eu_body
  )

  first_chats_eu$firstChat[first_chats_eu$associate == i] <- fromJSON(toJSON(firstchats_eu_connection$hits$hits), flatten = TRUE)[1]$`_source.time`
}
```

The problem is that it always produces the following message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "firstChat", value = list("2017-06-08T00:17:01.118Z",  : 
  replacement has 445 rows, data has 446
```

I have looked at other answers on SO but the solutions appear to be specific to each case, and thus not applicable to mine.

What could be causing this?

If it is of any use, this loop sometimes partially succeeds, in that it returns the first 34 results and then fails for all other rows after that point.

**Data frame:**

```
structure(list(associate = c("Pm0jYumSjx", "PbjmBqnIdY", "Vq3VblKpZn", 
"JUCx0MOygt", "9IxVPXPGvQ", "FUUobAsS2Z", "uflgsKMNze", "VzeedmQuiv", 
"BWYbDAIPkr", "PNCzrO3TRA", "zwemlUrxQE", "y19AiLUxLN", "4hhURCoC8H", 
"Ak13YJF63y", "aoQI4Ncrt4", "syaulepdzW", "ISdTwUISIG", "wncQ5pXq88", 
"MYbsg1E2EQ", "OhkAz5aren", "A2wqC9F1WR", "ZDVmRyHkUY", "n5kKRmTMzj", 
"mfek2ukQXk", "9Tz6HWSBTd", "b7JdFFaL7M", "TetbzmItfe", "NfCPXPfA8G", 
"fc3QfKEgoI", "lWOiSbqDkN", "PXU7CqGO1S", "kEgnBQeUVH", "Zk182RMS4W", 
"vzF3lzDKlx", "92PThwjFeO", "hunSRzc1p9", "n2xvlXoTS3", "AzJIMGGn4I", 
"8DAm5dFPtN", "Qk6Dl1wgAG", "b6Z1C2RgYk", "FsHvmjOWu8", "SHqTI9YFFx", 
"xhKjx5JJin", "RAPQXUNJbF", "vuq1KKylZY", "sBcaWcjEsk", "B4Z2TYT02E", 
"u6iEcDrjRL", "Tv8FVDmFlN", "lTS0ZT24vu", "i2I0kykYo0", "N9Nqwu7XiM", 
"0wFw3bY5De", "KEcKE4DRdT", "JcZWhBasDE", "FfLrHsnrT5", "ibOCROEWcG", 
"b9K3V27GH7", "1TMLQZS5eR", "Yfo5sO7Hyj", "Q09sg2jrsI", "byzMzoS8QV", 
"NKLbLwDA4b", "iKkQUDBXln", "Rutbihe39R", "T00E44PAAf", "PSKIFW2Bi3", 
"ewJjvrT8H6", "rudiPWdyHj", "gShZwgHn0m", "dQmluy3ilM", "kO2hP2SNzJ", 
"hG8iLjN6BD", "GuDBMuoht6", "AOzBVHetmK", "inSAsVD12e", "tYSXKOEhQB", 
"ie5m9sDcd5", "31XpEIYYEd", "qrh9kSiCTh", "6cGqFJB1vh", "VPqvH3dHnz", 
"tmg2iLu1f6", "a7nBJlzYRt", "D8jHgvvZfY", "pMwjxAV1iP", "0hD2vZYxf7", 
"JFuSGQZmYq", "dCu6ebaRzu", "8kFAGY52xO", "8dq2kAKbnP", "FL3RRY9dbb", 
"kJhRRpLQDu", "bRkAyVrvBf", "mMHRUeQEjd", "3ATe60itju", "t1IdGh570n", 
"LT7PLxWjKh", "zanyzD8KHy", "zo2fOcIflj", "pLhZhgBSd6", "iTzqXtTlVc", 
"6ZGJSIjfUK", "bp0JOkgL2n", "4fHmIsuzoR", "wr8pS9BIGn", "XjBFbgCbA6", 
"aBDfBMlyhl", "bjpWS5Zi1d", "1m8RnFavmk", "BCbEV3YcWs", "WO3z2kXsHv", 
"W4ziF0GFYp", "Dvdpoq3gZJ", "TeO490YGfr", "sMuDgfHnOY", "IBH2U18pLr", 
"iWfUpGFrvN", "JiqDLRGEFX", "kyNo0jk8Z1", "93HElGBOHz", "5ZJCyJrVoO", 
"2XS3g6lGJN", "BcLA5ChZHs", "kEVIPyQENZ", "xEHCoCz4kk", "2VP9YQHg0z", 
"NE1PnnqgGk", "Ay1r8aB1p3", "KX6pPK8IYt", "oaPI42kqwl", "G8DQ2GKget", 
"rrUNVhvaL6", "e1V2GXIIQi", "S1ABORMzvC", "P5SHJFevse", "G5oyD7KyNk", 
"96uS2gpKKW", "oVokuIkcBH", "uvZwOIZkhC", "9g3a3lkaqK", "sL3CM1Ydmp", 
"CeRfpJxt5l", "gywxLgJfwk", "ykryX7GvTZ", "6G3LCq9dTM", "zcbQHDmYlm", 
"vb9zQCBcsC", "CHQR1sudJt", "aSPIsQtBW9", "vUF6TTncxg", "mfZwbqTdqs", 
"6KFAVH1JfU", "5VC1MoGAPL", "dBT7WbCPbg", "hsiLXdTOlX", "RYCLZhFY90", 
"q9SsmoL8Ig", "eHawNS1jr0", "GVgIzKB9UB", "v1RSMGUZAb", "2arkjePApM", 
"FVNiv2T5i2", "2YI036CYSi", "bEe9hMOuPw", "SYHAbSA4Bo", "kIxHklYUvm", 
"ea0HZio45e", "bJLyBCIDLq", "UOX1xE4I4m", "DUlIH2h7wi", "MYF1ueeXfe", 
"1tOV5TEEK5", "oPt6FcBGj5", "jvyfvuEgaZ", "lNVTpT4hA9", "HqDMYSu1lC", 
"al11gInzgN", "hIC4Q5JlBH", "ujvEUtatGU", "wU4B2gFWsH", "UbC2Fnef7t", 
"4PMafQHS86", "pzgyPSDDR2", "HajTJzwD6s", "Vmb16EuXQd", "MLImxndCP8", 
"JioVLn85XG", "ezeN1Jrfz7", "X3dVvzFpO7", "jXWNcEJF40", "1Dlxb9sFY1", 
"I2rDM0GCQY", "ItEc62tlMD", "BQSEE0aw5j", "PcKSaFFCjc", "UZOQv40QpR", 
"TpTUfAkH2j", "102Qub695d", "iYMYFVeO3a", "9q6smEyLHE", "Oft5GPL1Kz", 
"RNgREArWYp", "6JpBEX0t5E", "FQGSnKhEHZ", "qhH4yU4GF4", "smal1c8nZI", 
"XM22Vo5TMb", "wVNGHFxsrw", "bOhSejjY4F", "XstvxG2evH", "YSeaBFnCxC", 
"aHvosVBvWF", "ECa32iNWUP", "ntNOwcH86q", "6sBSxrENuN", "TKrEDKGBP4", 
"7goCPMibBX", "owne4NwFBU", "DzbUeksk3x", "GFmnRMNXLn", "z03bGKnR4K", 
"yrickhqzXO", "orNL3qgRs5", "aZDhxK3MnT", "GfjLnYebLi", "ABzJScG4aF", 
"MzDl5sIcEv", "nDPQ5ryX60", "wzYLWcEGt7", "fg4yEOCrMg", "cOxDNFSVJ1", 
"N3xJGamqYg", "YCWeSx7FdA", "nS7j6dlHW1", "v8xHPHvF9I", "WTgftXNmQv", 
"JhhRGHAiAv", "kA95elFmbl", "6SBhLJ10MA", "zB8PDYd3yi", "Id0K9bUgkh", 
"wBkgvnElHb", "kQnwwfc7kJ", "6hNV4Y1C4A", "AmA4Y13eQd", "flON1gpb6N", 
"f5DopCEFwK", "boFD2o0FU2", "yd2OuCsCSL", "nDzEFEpz2D", "fweWiQ6x6l", 
"G1mT217Z6l", "rFt9fevsgu", "MGtbd36gdp", "K48dwo2BDj", "fzDa2HHq8k", 
"q3MmPsZKB4", "O9yTAKQlCN", "tDpjeKpWIY", "wOgm4P7503", "4kXj6O1TWk", 
"GTgOP6Ik3U", "AcCdmoQqtn", "F5fwdhj5l3", "AJnCAwFOdi", "ssvby6VgQp", 
"qzh7xCHMLl", "T2VySRQ0M0", "0yfnFPWynB", "L7PqHs1f0H", "83GzTa9bxh", 
"DOGXIreUyo", "PDsqEWLsu5", "sN3JstovsG", "knZx7l2hsk", "asCBJPBgTg", 
"ytAmW9sTAP", "S9vuzwn13O", "nrXFr6Ww5O", "sFUB1beOAx", "CyCvAIDs5q", 
"z2jmTzZVAo", "Zdd2fiDPVe", "MOQP5vAj8W", "rjx4tHVh6E", "2G3dquHI2q", 
"BruK8mqzVI", "GAB1feRTKE", "TPwJ8jp6j2", "mprSpIdRuJ", "qBaU7KERwq", 
"QNfCFKWXv5", "6IdSIlfhrz", "19SMR3CQID", "LxnNlx8DsD", "TEJeH1bZXz", 
"bTmafqEayN", "9X18BUOA36", "NoYo4tT3oG", "yj5TyZZyNT", "kPVRWBJRXM", 
"H3kVwfzGTe", "vq7qUUqGUr", "GLDCR4av3A", "xiYU2MDc6c", "qOGqanHpjw", 
"5BaW31f0Nr", "4dJwcfCqkA", "UJzHhwFZRe", "dec0Qlz3eK", "0l7WDqbZb0", 
"MMwd72FDCL", "EDMkdKIWMy", "2zLQmEuKpY", "1SUMAUhkZc", "BxXiWBTb8w", 
"zFdVjcL7qz", "pfPOEmMTei", "HzjyCETszF", "b26xszWUlP", "AseQsOAqqY", 
"lvDbmLqnyg", "L5WxvWWAyt", "X5WUvRm2BY", "t6XCwcOinz", "FG7pLFG8Uw", 
"yLpMyvmHb2", "7Ac9pVAF0B", "sDN9UHNGm4", "9Z1L7RtlA3", "bVb8hjn1ju", 
"F4nLAs89VO", "kB4aIQEpkf", "lov4Q42w2B", "jnFjq8covm", "tIuHe5uCaC", 
"qsAssEo3Qr", "mW3HVtDHQj", "pFoLBb4EfI", "5UA1lbRTrF", "s1qrkLbTIU", 
"RQrW6CtY7C", "xVIb7ymcmW", "Iw3AvXAlZK", "yW0P3oHRKp", "Ivf463pZ3k", 
"07OAzJ3LMW", "5nB6O3rLm3", "QsI7HSwDZ6", "YN6V6flLDk", "B5RXoyGmeY", 
"gt1VgDERw1", "FS2yKGf1vg", "BpUytkzSeS", "fKFSxBU4QG", "ueBhiB7lig", 
"c901c019c5", "MKADBViZNz", "Vcb76RpM0z", "PnIACGOY1I", "EIYwDIB3od", 
"B30kGNViyD", "YuAuj81ULa", "HBRNcgXjly", "CNFYrTCnkB", "0NG6oAIhrv", 
"39OL0da3JB", "pEYsCPrejG", "imUsAjHivl", "D6QCEqCeEN", "pbARKO6WHG", 
"mtx6Brb5rP", "oaLUE44A5W", "AgrZaWAFsg", "yvOMkkIZ1m", "Z6fXosz4Fa", 
"2fthCJ5DpQ", "yzDHP6VC3C", "oACH3KkPl4", "OUpJGlVe7Q", "rTUsgI4HB1", 
"BG0bfaNntS", "T6DgmUfrMS", "tjMwvgas9N", "gSYzWEbwH6", "6P9pRD9jft", 
"h7jgprw5ZI", "9RYqSSNP4s", "pv51ewuo8J", "kPHNzPAsy7", "qDg9oiE5vO", 
"8PxDnGjkT9", "czyeqBbnOJ", "uHSx9FbBZy", "Z2mdkJk7Tk", "A9lBq2pPB7", 
"1MjXRGUpCL", "oS6oAKFqvi", "Ro2Cpuw7nB", "4LjJWDFiJU", "ASrmSlOd4j", 
"f9BBXMzBju", "VHdzp3okgg", "zgCdOvoFoJ", "vm7dLCBAXu", "aohXymMv9M", 
"rsATydK2xE", "l6erf0NNN8", "wtcNWItEK5", "XO9BfYHSuJ", "FIsDrDMEM6", 
"wThiyvldqW", "n49e2LohLA", "ISPVKeaL8B", "QavdvrKCrJ", "Oc5GaqMvsD", 
"dBgH5abgm4", "jbxXIMi5T3", "wOEbpBhvJO", "EcSEO5x8Aa", "IPYmcletaC", 
"RccyJrXYSQ", "F044DDAL9U", "xCUcsCDnQd", "wkF3tx7M5N", "RNMO5oH2ce", 
"KEUArjG58B", "TfBcBOhVZQ", "BpjQjjlTDg", "wSsnje6q39", "ITAESdcmae", 
"XTzpZzZFxy", "UutDWic510", "TMgewBSCgi", "mhEM43wLRC", "FwXswHZJzn", 
"jqvBb6v6CY", "1YJDIwy9q2", "ea7Hx9RXNl", "cAYtXFKDvK", "R8DhTwSDmg", 
"a54nasvwuX", "bnNkM8nimD", "FSSGwmo5Qh"), accountCreation = structure(c(1521647203.675, 
1519339418.982, 1520978846.791, 1521462847.464, 1521219528.448, 
1525602918.744, 1521039530.235, 1521026513.49, 1521802344.631, 
1523790193.342, 1523699716.79, 1522159355.724, 1520935894.587, 
1525529531.887, 1524575967.739, 1521127935.332, 1521047835.094, 
1521101424.346, 1520997141.963, 1521025271.346, 1521106469.437, 
1520952168.279, 1522939980.072, 1521644559.484, 1520962152.598, 
1520946377.448, 1521114036.503, 1523303212.556, 1520948768.796, 
1521281304.856, 1521484713.426, 1521314445.804, 1521632072.396, 
1524399853.238, 1524063742.962, 1524048668.223, 1521231047.543, 
1524157639.65, 1521209831.34, 1521475186.089, 1521724609.138, 
1523533039.228, 1523702955.539, 1522488605.67, 1521890183.374, 
1521642579.3, 1522228581.673, 1523525372.293, 1521195229.708, 
1520940268.528, 1521044364.138, 1527678100.482, 1524600058.621, 
1522777239.275, 1523870518.667, 1521369133.225, 1522232575.542, 
1521198325.682, 1523360584.136, 1521813258.386, 1521627226.595, 
1521033049.721, 1523452387.623, 1522236488.509, 1521198246.297, 
1524671994.275, 1521720640.095, 1522242402.263, 1521637447.34, 
1521718413.354, 1521290525.148, 1521530545.831, 1521022229.054, 
1521054255.295, 1522147616.899, 1521115359.397, 1525349801.15, 
1520943213.673, 1523610221.63, 1521478193.229, 1521889281.441, 
1523701184.22, 1521810788.09, 1520946831.645, 1521471304.719, 
1521561858.612, 1521893506.908, 1521048628.327, 1521116277.724, 
1522765167.032, 1521286311.531, 1521125237.2, 1521887929.78, 
1525159037.328, 1524135123.072, 1519230466.413, 1521030848.111, 
1520956865.733, 1521592739.521, 1521457270.104, 1521736081.412, 
1521736093.529, 1522159760.701, 1524053386.664, 1524496291.977, 
1524216088.817, 1520936977.191, 1520953090.937, 1521212807.586, 
1521803151.728, 1521801343.725, 1524055557.569, 1522767163.557, 
1521729513.656, 1524316353.148, 1520935603.264, 1523960278.276, 
1521499028.577, 1521643199.88, 1524483302.128, 1525335512.042, 
1521373117.292, 1520879030.594, 1521023257.287, 1521022157.451, 
1523800300.841, 1520935205.484, 1521738187.203, 1521280970.99, 
1521213783.986, 1523970332.086, 1522053669.333, 1521738166.805, 
1522945933.897, 1520952792.799, 1524757978.638, 1521111905.664, 
1524295064.907, 1521025774.074, 1522320956.043, 1521655757.989, 
1521195220.823, 1521016193.598, 1521730985.238, 1521739086.354, 
1520936329.814, 1520941866.452, 1521308647.796, 1520942541.479, 
1520932451.164, 1520932450.409, 1524233637.038, 1523542112.437, 
1521891391.694, 1520941112.597, 1521981704.61, 1524126540.184, 
1521452436.923, 1521681150.112, 1521021271.162, 1523113077.121, 
1524135121.181, 1521225075.835, 1521200485.608, 1521463364.621, 
1522340866.586, 1522675782.65, 1522061257.085, 1520935213.165, 
1521111379.722, 1522405319.784, 1521021777.312, 1521062469.007, 
1524653489.931, 1521216029.087, 1520932450.074, 1522483910.384, 
1521019100.815, 1524483561.903, 1521196200.601, 1521141925.275, 
1524608679.675, 1520935615.677, 1524766524.32, 1521019881.426, 
1520936989.662, 1523036547.916, 1521196426.438, 1521210908.376, 
1521628649.889, 1521280983.286, 1521300046.167, 1524738218.644, 
1523543199.814, 1521200519.952, 1524914417.224, 1524652840.984, 
1525862276.545, 1521027321.217, 1521104801.584, 1521223553.524, 
1521211503.42, 1521921773.167, 1520946989.043, 1523445841.807, 
1521725990.924, 1521977244.334, 1521627508.652, 1525969006.645, 
1525969022.093, 1521812644.345, 1520932449.817, 1521458377.453, 
1521020768.777, 1521304861.478, 1520947823.441, 1521205017.765, 
1520953961.96, 1520940974.834, 1523182530.64, 1521886711.101, 
1521393592.616, 1521377252.798, 1521455570.819, 1521477410.136, 
1524502991.311, 1521568209.362, 1520970930.145, 1523821413.628, 
1521541778.729, 1519236437.627, 1523702049.192, 1522173164.254, 
1524657516.266, 1521735865.479, 1521466638.454, 1521813538.683, 
1521476092.325, 1521150151.59, 1521565928.114, 1522758779.981, 
1521479231.715, 1520935850.699, 1521025111.789, 1522867701.541, 
1521471989.26, 1524744993.667, 1520950428.393, 1523536553.54, 
1522421382.988, 1521546156.87, 1521028394.686, 1521050335.668, 
1521020456.866, 1522229659.937, 1521025286.049, 1521122727.912, 
1521026467.854, 1521450006.649, 1521219087.52, 1521469866.623, 
1521197195.734, 1521105260.349, 1521011471.989, 1521190524.789, 
1521452303.022, 1520933421.224, 1521115127.677, 1523884939.943, 
1520961138.002, 1521016753.264, 1521016893.143, 1521017010.196, 
1521017173.526, 1521017281.13, 1521017606.628, 1521117180.29, 
1521117300.792, 1521125450.611, 1521132242.791, 1521205674.621, 
1521205950.641, 1521215731.346, 1521459082.156, 1521460316.99, 
1521482702.085, 1521482815.695, 1521482903.143, 1521483099.712, 
1521483278.868, 1521483371.324, 1521540692.887, 1521543890.489, 
1521544034.707, 1521544160.551, 1521544235.273, 1521544330.989, 
1521544485.786, 1521544609.88, 1521544764.696, 1521553643.038, 
1521553739.931, 1521590910.434, 1521731535.229, 1521731535.928, 
1521731546.759, 1521802978.117, 1521886145.182, 1521886194.283, 
1521886413.213, 1521889580.687, 1522052985.205, 1522069337.077, 
1522063483.939, 1522166738.438, 1522250898.347, 1522340911.64, 
1522942459.588, 1523359215.503, 1523397047.86, 1523437988.256, 
1523438083.426, 1523445420.319, 1523447633.945, 1523455566.243, 
1523458605.986, 1523541116.105, 1523615795.787, 1523879249.334, 
1523890699.033, 1523979871.23, 1523980654.125, 1524045405.981, 
1524056257.89, 1524154119.955, 1524159979.146, 1524393026.557, 
1524393845.931, 1524478733.191, 1524494492.895, 1524495293.313, 
1524500425.993, 1524500660.969, 1524585635.173, 1524641288.518, 
1524659670.369, 1524667611.839, 1524668269.638, 1524672949.857, 
1524673079.627, 1524673178.774, 1524912901.694, 1525006502.237, 
1525034518.791, 1525076940.386, 1525079238.038, 1525079979.214, 
1525081785.524, 1525083082.759, 1525085456.7, 1525176437.685, 
1525253930.6, 1525255054.744, 1525259664.818, 1525261014.423, 
1525261500.246, 1525287238.277, 1525346162.325, 1525350313.866, 
1525451045.815, 1525686874.633, 1525800629.92, 1525865551.171, 
1525877902.633, 1525942349.151, 1525945093.268, 1526141141.217, 
1526142261, 1526301362.64, 1526301431.797, 1526301861.592, 1526302079.545, 
1526324313.439, 1526327287.226, 1526383076.912, 1526394120.405, 
1526394871.906, 1526395540.302, 1526396440.737, 1526467461.013, 
1526474515.013, 1526474851.867, 1526474950.656, 1526475027.807, 
1526572192.208, 1526899111.332, 1526903749.417, 1526911124.083, 
1526978640.406, 1526992033.825, 1527005249.155, 1527062775.068, 
1527065597.18, 1527070549.853, 1527072673.61, 1527086220.387, 
1527087986.751, 1527149254.527, 1527149382.032, 1527149716.254, 
1527149851.777, 1527150283.992, 1527150450.301, 1527150553.517, 
1527150666.548, 1527165902.1, 1527165998.747, 1527166128.254, 
1527166243.866, 1527170994.7, 1527171081.964, 1527171158.104, 
1527171239.335, 1527174965.995, 1527175065.505, 1527236752.65, 
1527237081.146, 1527237162.074, 1527237333.16, 1527237518.202, 
1527237606.934, 1527237676.797, 1527237786.63, 1527237891.106, 
1527237979.302, 1527238310.444, 1527238397.71, 1527238467.749, 
1527247882.085, 1527247921.493, 1527253757.25, 1527261991.607, 
1527262528.413, 1527590487.952, 1527590606.241, 1527590748.119
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), firstChat = list("2017-12-23T19:02:03.112Z", 
    "2017-06-08T00:17:01.118Z", "2016-12-11T15:20:54.019Z", "2017-03-10T11:41:44.036Z", 
    "2017-02-07T17:00:13.338Z", "2017-02-09T17:56:32.961Z", "2017-02-06T16:34:19.095Z", 
    "2017-06-07T12:11:15.257Z", "2017-02-21T14:58:31.850Z", "2017-02-09T15:17:40.920Z", 
    "2017-02-09T14:43:02.026Z", "2017-02-20T15:37:56.756Z", "2017-03-08T15:04:17.341Z", 
    "2017-03-03T19:43:19.287Z", "2017-07-16T09:47:28.713Z", "2017-03-30T17:57:47.205Z", 
    "2017-03-20T20:09:41.879Z", "2017-03-22T15:09:21.433Z", "2017-03-22T19:02:20.977Z", 
    "2017-04-06T10:46:50.105Z", "2017-04-19T17:12:18.318Z", "2017-04-21T15:21:48.603Z", 
    "2017-04-20T14:12:07.052Z", "2017-04-21T11:33:10.867Z", "2017-04-20T08:58:52.326Z", 
    "2017-04-21T13:34:01.145Z", "2017-04-24T17:50:07.694Z", "2017-04-21T11:02:15.512Z", 
    "2017-05-24T10:56:42.089Z", "2017-05-06T13:26:43.845Z", "2017-05-10T17:44:43.533Z", 
    "2017-05-04T15:14:47.320Z", "2017-05-16T15:28:05.820Z", "2017-05-17T19:29:16.809Z", 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
446L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: As you say... possibly unique to your data, BUT my instance of R reports: "data set ‘first_chats_eu’ not found"

Comment: Data set added. Also, it only works for the first 34 instances, after which point it fails which tells me that the code and data set are both fine but something else keeps causing the loop to fail...

Comment: Run the loop, and when it fails, look at the value of what the replacement value (`fromJSON(toJSON(firstchats_eu_connection` ...).  See if it matches your expectations.  It's hard for us to help without access to your database.

Comment: The replacement value is in precisely the format that I was expecting it to be (i.e. `"2017-06-08T00:17:01.118Z"`).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can you read the data into a `list` first and then match it back into your `data.frame` and see where the missing values are?